# Do I need the "flow control" component on my furnace

Tags: plumbing, furnace, hot-water

**Context:**
My furnace supplies tank-less domestic hot water to my small house. The cold water pipe going into the furnace has a "flow control" component that limits the flow to 3gpm. I understand that higher flow rates could result in my domestic hot water not being fully heated before it gets to a faucet because it went through the furnace too quickly.

**Problem:**
This "Flow Control" component has failed (from age), and only allows a small trickle of water though. (I am certain it is this component because I have way to vent water from either side of it.)

**Question:**
Since water flow is limited by my faucets and shower anyways, can I just remove the component instead of replacing it.

Comment: You'll know when you try. It depends on 1) supply pressure, and 2) actual flow rate due to local demand. We can't really say. I'd give it a go.

Comment: If it was also a pressure regulator, I'd worry about the full supply pressure damaging the furnace, but assuming that's not the case you probably don't _need_ it.  You just won't have very hot water if you turn on two faucets at the same time (most single faucets and showers are less than 3gpm anyway).

Comment: I removed the flow control device and discovered that it had failed from debris stuck in it. Everything works fine without it.